# C++ Function Calling with Parameter in int main

Tags: c++

How would I go about calling the void menu function in the int main function?
I tried different things for the parameter but i'm confused on how to call the menu function.

Updated It since  required me to post the full Coding to better under stand my problem, but I just want a way to call the menu function.

```
//Compiling Error

WordData.cpp: In function 'int main()':
WordData.cpp:25:6: error: too few arguments to function 'void menu(std::string, int)'
   25 | menu();
      |      ^
WordData.cpp:20:6: note: declared here
   20 | void menu(string,int);
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "WordData.h"

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
//WordData.cpp
//prototype
void menu(string,int);

int main(){

//This problem here
menu();
//............
    return 0;
}

void menu(string wrd,int cnt)
{
    WordData wd = WordData(wrd,cnt);
    int selection;
    bool quit=false;
    do  
    {
        cout<<endl;
        cout<< "1: PARALLEL ITERATIVE";
        cin>>selection;
        cout<<endl;
    switch(selection)
        {
        case 1:
            //this here
            wd.setWord(wrd);
            //.........
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Works 2";
            break;
        case 8:
            quit=true;
        }
    } while(quit==false);


}
```

```
#ifndef WORDDATA_H
#define WORDDATA_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class WordData {
    
 public:  //PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

  /*****************************************************************/
  /*    Function name:   constructor                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Description:     Will construct a default word data object.*/
  /*                     Default values are an empty string zero as*/
  /*                     the count.                */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Parameters:      string wrd - Word to be placed in object  */
  /*                     int cnt - Value to be placed in counter   */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Member Type:                                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Return Value:    none                                      */
  /*****************************************************************/  
  WordData(string wrd = "", int cnt = 0);
  
  //SETS
  //
  /*****************************************************************/
  /*    Function name:   setWord                                   */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Description:     Will set the object's string.             */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Parameters:      string wrd - Word to be placed in object  */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Member Type:                                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Return Value:    none                                      */
  /*****************************************************************/
  void setWord(string wrd);

  /*****************************************************************/
  /*    Function name:   setCount                                  */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Description:     Will set the occurence counter.           */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Parameters:      int cnt - Value to be placed in counter   */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Member Type:                                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Return Value:    none                                      */
  /*****************************************************************/
  void setCount(int cnt);

  /*****************************************************************/
  /*    Function name:   setWordData                               */  
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Description:     Will set both the object's string and the */
  /*                     object's occurence count.                 */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Parameters:      string wrd - Word to be placed in object  */
  /*                     int cnt - Value to be placed in counter   */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Member Type:                                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Return Value:    none                                      */
  /*****************************************************************/
  void setWordData(string,int);

  //GETS
  //
  /*****************************************************************/
  /*    Function name:   getWord                                   */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Description:     Will retrieve the object's string.        */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Parameters:      none                                      */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Member Type:                                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Return Value:    string                                    */
  /*****************************************************************/
  string getWord() const;

  /*****************************************************************/
  /*    Function name:   getCount                                  */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Description:     Will retrieve the occurence counter.      */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Parameters:      none                                      */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Member Type:                                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Return Value:    int                                       */
  /*****************************************************************/  
  int getCount() const;
  
  /*****************************************************************/
  /*    Function name:   operator ++                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Description:     Will increment the occurrence counter.    */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Parameters:      int inc - Value to be incremented by      */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Member Type:                                               */
  /*                                                               */
  /*    Return Value:    none                                      */
  /*****************************************************************/
  WordData& operator++();   // preincrement
  WordData operator++(int); // postincrement

 private: //PRIVATE VARIABLES
  
  string word;  //Object's word
  int count;    //Object's occurrence counter

};
```

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question for us to answer it with specific code. The definition of `menu()` clearly says it requires two parameters. You need to pass meaningfull values for those two parameters. If you don't know how to do this, then you should read a C++ tutorial or watch a YouTube video that will teach you how.

Comment: It seems your are trying to learn C++ on SO. Don't do it, read a C++ book.

Comment: Added Compiling Error and Coding where it mattered, theres 2 files, WordData.cpp and WordData.h,

Comment: What parts of the error message do you not understand? The number (zero) of arguments that you provided when calling `menu` is less than the number (two) of arguments that a call to `menu` requires. How can you fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you define `void menu(string wrd,int cnt)`, you must have to call the `menu()` function passing with two parameters like `menu("code",10)` from main function.
You can pass any valid `string` and `int` in the `menu()`.

Comment: Thanks, a simple yet well explained Solution. LifeSaver.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string> 
void menu(string,int);

int main()
{

    //This problem here
    menu("hello",1);
    //............
    return 0;
}

void menu(string wrd,int cnt)
{
    std::cout << wrd << " " << cnt;
}
```

For a better answer poet the errors you are getting. Either from the compiler or from run time.

Comment: added more coding to help explain my question

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass parameters through the function. Try the following code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   void menu(string,int);

   int main() {
     menu("string",13);
   }

   void menu(string wrd,int cnt)
   {
      cout<< wrd << "\t"  << cnt <<endl;
   }
```

Comment: added more coding to help explain my question